# Refresh value in text field with JavaScript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that calculate price for a product. I'm not JavaScript developer so my knowledge is very limited.

By changing the value in the text field script calculate price for product.

```
 <input type="text" value="" name="options[22]" class="input-text"
 onfocus="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
```

Problem is that the script triggers only if the following is done:

1. insert value into the textfield
2. click somewhere outside the textfield
3. click back into the text field

All I need is a button saying refresh that by clicking it will have functionality of step 2 and step above.

I'm not sure if I explained it properly so if there is any more information required to resolve this issue please let me know.

Here is the link to the site.

http://www.floorstodoors.mldemo.co.uk/spotlight/oak-value-lacquered-3-strip.html

The field im trying to amend/add refresh button is Enter Square Metre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand you, but is this what you need?

```
<input type="text" value="" name="options[22]" class="input-text">
<input type="button" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" value="Refresh" />
```

A button with an click-event listener, so that when you click the refresh-button the `opConfig.reloadPrice()` method gets executed.

**Edit based on comment:**

I'm not sure what JavaScript library you are using, but you have these two lines in you code that seems to add event-listeners to the input with id `qty`.

```
$('qty').observe('focus',function(){
    $('qty').setValue($('qty').getValue().replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
});     
$('qty').observe('focus',this.getFromQties.bind(this))
```

They are listening for the `focus` event, thus only triggers when your input field gains focus.

If you modify those to listen for the keyup event instead, I believe it will work better. Without being familiar with the framework, I guess the only thing to change would be this:

```
$('qty').observe('keyup',function(){
    $('qty').setValue($('qty').getValue().replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
});     
$('qty').observe('keyup',this.getFromQties.bind(this))
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions did not work for me. I think best will be if Ill just provide link to the site as my explenation isn't clear.

http://www.floorstodoors.mldemo.co.uk/spotlight/oak-value-lacquered-3-strip.html

Its the Enter Square Metre: field.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dom The calculator seems to work for me? Or what is the problem there?

Comment: Thanks for looking. Calculator as you have notived works perfectly fine. Although there is a text field "Enter Square Metre:" under it that allows to change total amount required.  You can insert your own value there but in order to change the Total Price you will need to click out outside the text field and then back inside it. When I am trying to acheave is a button that will update the Total Price after changing "Enter Square Metre" clicking on it.

Comment: now ive hit another wall!

The calculator above become unresponsive. Which is logical. The solution wont be as simple i guess.  Now whenever I add fields in the calculator above "Enter Square Metre:" it will change the value but will not trigger the Total Price. I'm sorry for being such a pain on this one, but is there anything can be done about it please?

Answer (score 2):

You'd add your event to a button, and retrieve a reference to your input by assigning an ID:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="options[22]" id="price" class="input-text" />
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="reloadPrice();" />

function reloadPrice() {
    var price = "0.00"; // set your price here

    // get a ref to your element and assign value
    var elem = document.getElementById("price");
    elem.value = price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onchange or onblur instead of onfocus!

Answer (score 0):

use onchange. This will activate anytime the value changes:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="options[22]" class="input-text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
```

Answer (score 0):

First: this is JavaScript and not Java - so you have to be a javascript and not a java developer.

to solve your problem you can make a new button with a onclick attribute and execute your function there which you have in your onfocus attribute in the text-field.
or you can take another event - like onchange or onblur for instance..

```
<input type="text" onchange="..yourfunctionhere...">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
All I need is a button saying refresh that by clicking it will have functionality
```

For that you need a button with onclick listener,
do the below things.

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice();" />

<input type="text" value="" name="options[22]" class="input-text"/>
```